# How can I know the value of a checkBox marked with vueJS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I am finishing a project with Laravel and vueJS, but I have a problem. In a modal, I select a checkbox (there may be several or not) and that value of the marked checkbox, I need to keep it for when I press a button in another modal, the value of the checkbox is sent to the controller to make an update. It does well for me with the first check, but if I select another, the first one always takes me. I'm trying to catch it by class, but nothing, always take first.

I attach my current code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <div v-if="bonosUsuarioSolicitante.length == 0">No hay bonos disponibles</div>
                <div v-for="data in bonosUsuarioSolicitante" class="ml-5">

                    <label class="form-check-label">Tiempo Restante</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-3 codContrato" :value="data.codContrato" @click="iniciarActuacion">
                    <label class="form-check-label ml-5">{{data["tiempoRestanteBono"]}} Min</label>

                </div>
            </div>
```

There I put the values ​​of the checkbox inside the modal that calls the "startAction" function until there well. If all goes well, this modal is closed.

In another modal, I have this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="detenerActuacion">Detener Actuacion</button>
```

and this function is the one that I would update

```
detenerActuacion: function(){
        clearInterval(cronometro);

        let minutosContratados = $("#tiempoContratado").val();

        // Mínimo se va a restar 5 minutos a la actuación una vez iniciada.
        let minutosActuacion = 5

        let minutosEmpleados = document.getElementById("minutos").innerText;

        if(minutosEmpleados < minutosActuacion){
            minutosEmpleados = minutosActuacion;
        }


        // variables que van al controlador
        let tiempoEmpleadoCalculado = minutosContratados - minutosEmpleados;


        let mensaje = $("#mensajeActuacion").val();
        let codV3 = $("#codV3").val();
        let codContrato = $(".codContrato").val();
       
        let url = "/actualizarTiempo";
        axios
            .post(url, {
                        tiempoEmpleado: minutosEmpleados,
                        tiempoRestante: tiempoEmpleadoCalculado,
                        mensajeActuacion: mensaje,
                        codContrato: codContrato,
                        codV3: codV3,
                       }
                  )
            .then((response) => {
                $("#actuacionCorrecta").text("Actuación guardada con exito y tiempo del bono actualizado")
            })
            .catch(
                (error) => $("#actuacionError").append(error)

            );
    },
```

I have jQuery mixed and that it should not be done together with vueJS. In the first modal it is where I could get the codContrato which is what I need to update. Hence I try to capture it with class. As I say, the first one goes well ... But that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-model`, it could be very easy.

Check the following example code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div v-for="(data,index) in check_data" :key="index">
            <input type="checkbox" :value="data.id" @change="check()" v-model="checked">test {{data.value}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "example",
    data(){
        return {
            check_data:[{id:1,value:'a'},{id:2,value:'b'},{id:3,value:'c'}],
            checked:[],
        }

    },
    methods:{
        check(){
            console.log(this.checked);
        },

    }
}
</script>
```